# Is Open XML still a thing

Tags: xml, openxml

I've been researching Open XML and found little current information or tutorials. Open XML SDK 2.5 does not seem to have been updated since 2012. It does not seem to be totally dead, and I believe it is used for Office 365 documents. But it seems odd that there's so little info on it and most of that is very old. So has it been discontinued?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course, Office Open XML (OOXML), which is the data format used by every DOCX, XLSX, and PPT document, is *still a thing.*

OOXML is a data format standard (ECMA 376 and ISO/IEC 29500).  Perhaps you're actually asking about the status of the [Open XML SDK 2.5 library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425), which is just one of many libraries which can be used to process OOXML.  Development has continued as an open source project ([OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) with (currently) over 20 contributors, a latest release in August 2020, and a latest commit of four days ago.

So, yes, Open XML SDK is *still a thing* too.

Comment: I can only agree. In 2022, it's still a thing even if Microsoft stops developing the official SDKs.